# The coefficient of a specific monomial of the following polynomial

Tags: polynomials, sequences-and-series

Let the real polynomial 
$$f_{a,b,c}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1-x_2)^{2a+1}(x_2-x_3)^{2b+1}(x_3-x_1)^{2c+1},$$
where $a,b,c$ are nonnegative integers.

Let $m_{a,b,c}$ be the coefficient of the monomial $x_1^{a+c+1}x_2^{a+b+1}x_3^{b+c+1}$ in the expansion of $f_{a,b,c}(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

It is easy to see $m_{a,b,c}=0$ when two of $a,b,c$ are equal. I want to ask whether $m_{a,b,c}=0$ or not when $a,b,c$ are pairwise unequal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This coefficient $L$ is a constant term of the Laurent polynomial $g(x_1,x_2,x_3)=f(x_1,x_2,x_3)/x_1^{a+c+1}x_2^{a+b+1}x_3^{b+c+1}$, this guy $g$ satisfies $g(x_1,x_2,x_3)=-g(1/x_1,1/x_2,1/x_3)$, thus $L=-L$.

Comment: Fedor Petrov: Thank you very much for your answer! Your proof is very slick!

Answer (score 10):

The coefficient is always zero. I use the superb conventions of *Concrete Mathematics*: Sums are over all integers unless otherwise indicated, and $\binom{n}{k}$ is $0$ if $k<0$ or $>n \geq 0$.

Expanding by the binomial theorem, 
$$f_{abc} = \sum_{i,j,k} (-1)^{i+j+k} \binom{2a+1}{i} \binom{2b+1}{j} \binom{2c+1}{k} x_1^{2a+1-i+k} x_2^{2b+1-j+i} x_3^{2c+1-k+j}.$$

We want
$$\begin{array}{r@{}c@{}lcr@{}c@{}l}
a+c+1 &=& 2a+1-i+k &\implies& c-k &=& a-i\\
a+b+1 &=& 2b+1-j+i &\implies& a-i &=& b-j\\
b+c+1 &=& 2c+1-k+j &\implies& b-j &=& c-k  \\
\end{array}$$
so $(i,j,k) = (a+r, b+r, c+r)$ for some $r$. We need to evaluate
$$\sum_r (-1)^{a+b+c+3r} \binom{2a+1}{a+r} \binom{2b+1}{b+r} \binom{2c+1}{c+r}.$$

Pair off the $r$ and $1-r$ terms to get
$$(-1)^{a+b+c} \sum_{r \geq 0} \left[ (-1)^{3r} \binom{2a+1}{a+r} \binom{2b+1}{b+r} \binom{2c+1}{c+r} + \right.$$
$$\phantom{(-1)^{a+b+c} \sum_{r \geq 1}} \left. (-1)^{3-3r} \binom{2a+1}{a+1-r} \binom{2b+1}{b+1-r} \binom{2c+1}{c+1-r} \right].$$

The two terms in the square brackets cancel, and the sum is zero.

Comment: David Speyer: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

I don't have time to write a detailed answer but the following should help.

Blast your sum with Newton's binomial formula. That gives a sum over three indices $i,j,k$. The three equations you get on these indices by fixing the monomial of interest are linearly dependent, so you are left with a sum over just one index say $i$. I believe what you get is a ${}_3F_{2}$ terminating hypergeometric sum. Your quantity of interest is also a Wigner $3jm$-symbol or Clebsch-Gordan coefficient from the literature on quantum angular momentum. In general, determining the zeros of such numbers is an open problem, see my article ["The bipartite Brill-Gordan locus and angular momentum"](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00031-005-1111-8) with Jaydeep Chiplakatti for some references. If your case is sufficiently special (e.g., stretched coefficients) then you might be lucky enough to know if your coefficients are zero or not.

---

Edit:
As I said, I did not have time to look at your coefficient closely yesterday but from the other answers it turns out you are dealing with a trivial $3j$ zero.
In case you need more complicated analogues of your coefficients,
I am giving more details and perspective.

The Wigner $3jm$ symbol
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
j_1 & j_2 & J\\
m_1 & m_2 & m
\end{array}\right)
$$
is (up to trivial nonzero prefactors) the coefficient of $x_1^{j_1-m_1}x_2^{j_2-m_2}x_3^{J-m}$ in
$$
(x_1-x_2)^{j_1+j_2-J}(x_2-x_3)^{J+j_2-j_1}(x_3-x_1)^{J+j_1-j_2}\ .
$$

Therefore your coefficient is
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a+c+1 & a+b+1 & b+c+1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\ .
$$

If you look up page 2611 of the [article](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/26/11/011/meta) by Raynal, Van der Jeugt, Srinivasa Rao and Rajeswari, that we cited in my article mentioned above, you will see that your case (with all magnetic moments $m$ begin zero) is a trivial zero because the sum of the numbers on top is odd. If the sum is even the result
is nonzero and this is basically Dixon's Theorem for ${}_3F_2$ series.

You can find many more details on $3j$, $6j$, $9j$ symbols with precise signs, prefactors and all that in my other article with Chipalkatti ["The higher transvectants are redundant"](http://aif.cedram.org/aif-bin/item?id=AIF_2009__59_5_1671_0).

BTW, I just looked up citations to the Raynal et al. article, and there does not seem to have been much progress on understanding the zeros of $3jm$ coefficients.

Comment: Abdelmalek Abdesselam: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: no pbm. BTW may I ask what are you working on, how did the question above arise?

Answer (score 4):

This answer is really just a convoluted edition of Fedor's answer.  By Cauchy's theorem,
$$f_{abc} = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi
   \frac{(e^{i\theta_1}-e^{i\theta_2})^{2a+1}(e^{i\theta_2}-e^{i\theta_3})^{2b+1}(e^{i\theta_3}-e^{i\theta_1})^{2c+1}}{e^{i(a+c)\theta_1+i(a+b)\theta_2+i(b+c)\theta_3}}
\,d\theta_1\,d\theta_2\,d\theta_3.$$
Advancing each variable by $\pi$ changes the sign of the integrand but not the value of the integral, so its value must be 0.

To obtain the above integral start with the contour integral
$$\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^3} \oint\oint\oint \frac{(x_1-x_2)^{2a+1} (x_2-x_3)^{2b+1} (x_3-x_1)^{2c+1}}{x_1^{a+c+1}x_2^{a+b+1}x_3^{b+c+1}} \,dx_1dx_2dx_3 $$
that is just Cauchy's formula applied three times. Now take the contours to be unit circles $x_j=e^{i\theta_j}$ for $j=1,2,3$.

Comment: Brendan McKay: Thank you very much for your answer. Would you please explain how you got the equality above? Why is the denominator of the integrand $e^{i(2a+2b+2c)}$?

Comment: @user173856: I added an explanation.

Comment: Brendan McKay: I think the denominator of the integrand should be $e^{i(a+c)\theta_1}e^{i(a+b)\theta_2}e^{i(b+c)\theta_3}$ instead of $e^{i(2a+2b+2c)}$, am I wrong?

Comment: @User173856: You are not wrong!  Fortunately the correct denominator still has the property that it is unchanged if each variable is advanced by $\pi$.