# A question about the coefficient of a specific monomial in the expansion of the following polynomial

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, polynomials, sequences-and-series

By [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234564/the-coefficient-of-a-specific-monomial-of-the-following-polynomial) I asked before, 
I know that for any nonnegative integers $a$, $b$, $c$, the coefficient of the monomial $x_1^{a+c+1}x_2^{a+b+1}x_3^{b+c+1}$ in the expansion of
$$(x_1-x_2)^{2a+1}(x_2-x_3)^{2b+1}(x_3-x_1)^{2c+1}$$
is always zero.

Then I found for small nonnegative integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $k$, the coefficient of the monomial $x_1^{a+c+k}x_2^{a+b+k}x_3^{b+c+k}$ in the expansion of
$$(x_1-x_2)^{2a+2k}(x_2-x_3)^{2b+k}(x_3-x_1)^{2c}$$
is always nonzero.

I want to ask whether it is always right for all nonnegative integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $k$.

Comment: Is $k$ missing in the exponent of $(x_3-x_1)^{2c}$?

Comment: Hello, Seva, there is no $k$ in the exponent of $(x_3-x_1)^{2c}$, just $2c$.

Comment: Fwiw, Mathematica says that up to sign it is$$\binom{2 (a+k)}{a-b} \binom{2 c}{-b+c-k} \, _3F_2\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}\smash-a-b-2 k&&-2 b-k&&-b-c-k\\&a-b+1&&-b+c-k+1\end{array}1\right)$$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე What is this last 1 in the formula?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Sorry for bad TeXing - 1 means the value at 1 of this hypergeometric series. So the whole is the product of two binomial coefficients and of the value at 1 of the hypergeometric series with three upper parameters $-a-b-2k$, $-2b-k$, $-b-c-k$ and two lower parameters $a-b+1$, $-b+c-k+1$.

Comment: The coefficient is up to a sign equal to
$$\sum_{d} (-1)^d\binom{2a+2k}{a+k+d}\binom{2b+k}{b+d}\binom{2c}{c+d}$$